# Create a highchart for every dataset in R

Tags: r, highcharts

I have three data, that I have been able to plot using highchart:

```
hchart(data1)
hchart(data2)
hchart(data3)
```

Now what should I do if I want to have the three data in different plot but at the same page like this:[image: like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hw_grid as a quick fix if all of them have the same height:

```
library(htmltools)
library(highcharter)
h1 = hchart(prcomp(mtcars))
h2 = hchart(iris$Sepal.Width)
h3 = hchart(data.frame(x=1:10+runif(10),y=1:10+runif(10)),type="line")

combined = list(h1,h2,h3) %>% hw_grid(ncol=1,rowheight=250)
browsable(combined)
```

[image]

Or actually go down to using packages for combining htmlwidgets, where you can specify layout + row heights:

```
library(manipulateWidget)
combineWidgets(h1,h2,h3,ncol=1,rowsize=c(2,1,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out with htmltools package:

```
library(htmltools)
browsable(
  tagList(
    hchart(data1),
    hchart(data2),
    hchart(data3)
  )
 )
```

It works fine for every html output, and can be configured.

Answer (score 0):

`par` function is what you need.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
hchart(data1)
hchart(data2)
hchart(data3)
```

Comment: Doesn't work I believe it is because par is for multiple plots and hchart is html widget